# Dual Korean-American; how can I enter Russia with visa-free Korean passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, russia, dual-nationality, south-korea

I'm planning on flying to Moscow, Russia (SVO) from Incheon, Korea (ICN) in a few days.

I am a Korean-American dual citizen, having both a Korean passport and an American one. My names on both passports are different.

I noticed that Koreans can travel to Russia without a visa for 30 days, but U.S. Citizens require a visa.

I believe my boarding pass will be booked under the American name, but I won't be getting a visa. Will I be okay showing my Korean passport at Russian customs to enter?

This seems complicated and I've never been to Russia, so I don't know if I'll be pulled aside or rejected or how relaxed they are with this.

Comment: If an answer was helpful and solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, as it states on [the website of Consular Department of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Russia](http://www.kdmid.ru/docs.aspx?lst=country_wiki&it=/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F.aspx) about visa-free regime between Russian Federation and South Korea, **the duration of visa-free regime is 60 days**, not 30:

> Граждане государства одной Стороны, являющиеся владельцами проездных
>   документов и не имеющие намерения осуществлять трудовую деятельность,
>   учиться в учебных заведениях или проживать на территории государства
>   другой Стороны, освобождаются от требований получения виз для въезда,
>   пребывания, выезда или следования транзитом через территорию
>   государства другой Стороны. Срок каждого такого пребывания не может
>   превышать шестьдесят **(60) дней**.

Translation:

> Citizens of one of the states which possess a travel document which
>   don't intend to work, study or live on the territory of another state,
>   can enter, stay, exit or transit through the territory of another
>   state visa free. The duration of such a stay shall not exceed **60 days**.

Speaking about your dual citizenship, **as a citizen of South Korea, you have a privilege of entering Russia free of visa up to 60 days and your US citizenship doesn't abandon it.** So, just show your Korean passport to immigration officer and enjoy your stay in Russia.

Answer (score 5):

Russian border control **doesn't care about your boarding pass**, only your passport. So simply show your Korean passport.

At check-in in Incheon, in case your trip is indeed booked in your American name, just show both passports.